# É possível usar o between para filtrar buscas com um campo tipo character?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Por exemplo, se eu for fazer uma busca bo banco de dados de uma tabela com o preço dos produtos, eu uso na minha condição where: preco_produto between 10 and 550 mas e para eu fazer o mesmo tipo de busca em uma coluna do tipo character? Pois ao tentar fazer a busca usando o between ele acaba retornando um erro. Na tabela abaixo eu gostaria de filtrar da coluna carlis_nome todos os registros que ficassem entre por exemplo 400 mAh e 1400 mAh.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Teria que cortar a parte que é string.

Comment: Mostre como está fazendo a consulta e a estrutura da tabela (pode ser só as colunas relevantes para a consulta).

Comment: @bigown eu busco ela de umas outras 2 ou 3 tabelas. Eu queria mesmo saber como eu posso fazer para buscar usando o between ou se tem algum outro jeito de se fazer essa busca ou se por exemplo da para fazer alguma expressão regular para selecionar apenas os números da coluna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, porem string e numero são lidos de formas diferentes, o numero é lido respeitando os valores de cada posição, (unidades, dezenas, centenas etc.), já a string da esquerda para direita, portanto

`400 é maior que 1400, já que lido da esquerda para direita, o 4 é maior que o 1.`

Vi que suas TAGs são mysql, postgresql e sql, não uso o Mysql, mas no Postgres você pode tentar converter o campo string em int como:

`to_number(carlis_nome, '999999999') BETWEEN 400 AND 1400`.

No Mysql acho que terá que extrair o ' mAh' com:

`CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(campo,' mAh',-4),UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num`

Este não tenho como testar.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que isso resolve para vocÊ

**MYSQL**

```
 SELECT 
  campos
FROM 
  tabela
WHERE CAST(REPLACE( 
    LEFT(TRIM(`carlis_nome`), LOCATE(' ', TRIM(`carlis_nome `))),     
    '.','') AS SIGNED) BETWEEN 400 AND 1400;
```

**POSTGRES**

```
 SELECT 
  campos
FROM 
  tabela
WHERE CAST(regexp_replace(carlis_nome , '^(\\d)\.(\\d+)\\s.*?', E'\\1\\2') AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 400 AND 1400;
```